# #defines in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, c-preprocessor

How do #defines work in Objective-C?

I have a background in C/C++ and am now trying to pick up Objective-C. #defines don't seem to work in objective-c the same way they work in c and C++, where the compiler just replaces all references to the defines with what they are supposed to represent.

When I try to use #defines in Objective-C they only work sometimes. Like when I do something like this;

```
#define NUMBER 5

int myArray[NUMBER];
```

I get compiler errors saying there is a square bracket missing, where if I use this line instead it works fine;

```
int myArray[5];
```

Surely these should both be the same thing?

Also if I try to use #define value in any sort of equations I get similar sort of compiler errors. This code wont work;

```
#define NUMBER 5

float var = NUMBER * 0.2;
```

Where as this is fine;

```
float var = 5 * 0.2;
```

Anyone any idea why this might be, or how #defines are handled differently by the Objective-C compiler. I'm using XCode by the way, just incase that makes a difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`#define` in Objective-C works exactly the same way it works in C.  All of your examples work fine for me in a quick test I tried.  It's likely you have some other problem which is making the errors you're seeing - can you post your actual code and the text of your error messages?

Comment: Its a big project the #defines in use are in different files to where I want to use them, I would probably have to put up the whole project to find it. I must just be doing something silly, ill figure it out. At least now I know for sure it works the same as in C, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I've normally seen problems like that when I have an accidental semicolon in the `#define`.

Answer (score 2):

To figure out the behavior of your #defines, I would suggest using Xcode's Build->Preprocess command to see exactly what text the preprocessor is generating for you.

Comment: This is pretty useful!